# Parameters not getting passed properly

Tags: python, eval

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
def listFrom(here):
    print "[DBG] here: " + here

def book(here, there, amount):
    print "[DBG] here: " + here + "; there: " + there + "; amount: " + str(amount)

# Code that takes input and stores it into the string input

# Yes, I know this is dangerous, but it's part of a
# school assignment where we HAVE to use eval.
eval(input, {"__builtins__": {}, "listAll": listAll, "listFrom": listFrom, "listFromTo": listFromTo, "book": book, "about": about, "commands": commands, "book": book})
```

If I enter `listFrom('LON')`, the program returns `[DBG] here: LON` as expected. However, when I do `book('LON', 'MAN', 8)` I get an inexplicable `[DBG] here: ☺; there: ☻; amount: ♥`. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: where are you looking at the output? could you post the  IDLE session? otherwise no repro

Comment: Cannot replicate. What Python and which platform?

Comment: It appears to be working fine for me; can you post the code that you're using for getting user input? Also, I'd call the string variable something other than `input`, that's one of the built-in functions.  
What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works without problems in Python 2.6 on Linux/x86-32:

```
>>> def listFrom(here):
...     print "[DBG] here: " + here
... 
>>> def book(here, there, amount):
...     print "[DBG] here: " + here + "; there: " + there + "; amount: " + str(amount)
... 
>>> book('LON', 'MAN', 8)
[DBG] here: LON; there: MAN; amount: 8
>>> input = """book('LON', 'MAN', 8)"""
>>> eval(input, {"__builtins__": {}, "listFrom": listFrom, "book": book})
[DBG] here: LON; there: MAN; amount: 8
>>> eval("""listFrom('LON')""", {"__builtins__": {}, "listFrom": listFrom, "book": book})
[DBG] here: LON
```

What Python version are you using? On which OS/architecture?

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right. The code I isolated works fine, but I had done some wacky stuff that caused `eval` not to be executed at all in some cases.